# Android Fragment - Instantiation Exception in Layout

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have a layout which contains a `<fragment>` called MenuFragment. Whenever I launch the application howver, I get a  `Trying to instantiate a class com.usmaan.whackem.MenuFragment that is not a Fragment`.

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutHeader"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <fragment android:name="com.usmaan.whackem.MenuFragment"
        android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment{

    public MenuFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

I've tried

1) Adding an ID to the `<fragment>`

2) Adding a namespace to `<fragment>`

Comment: post the package name for fragment class

Comment: package com.usmaan.whackem;

Comment: what is `com.usmaan.myApp.MenuFragment`?? `myapp` and `whackem`!

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ignore that. It's meant to say `whackem`. I changed that myself. I'll change that now.

Comment: What does your activity extends and post  imports for fragment

Comment: Spot on! I was extending Activity and not FragmentActivity.

Comment: If @Raghunandan fixed it, then shouldn't he get the credit?

Comment: He didn't completely fix the issue. He was extremely helpful in helping me find the issue. And I did give him credit by giving him +1............

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by extending the Activity which holds the fragment from `FragmentActivity` and not `Activity`.